# Setting up Gulp with mean.io

Tags: gulp, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm pretty new to using the meanstack. I couldn't get mean.js to work. So I'm trying to get mean.io to function properly.

Currently it works fine, when I just run $ node server.

However when I install Gulp and try to run it that way, I get the following error:

> C:\Users\markl\Dropbox\Server\FS4>gulp
>   C:\Users\markl\Dropbox\Server\FS4\gulpfile.js:6 var env =
>   process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'; ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>       at require (module.js:385:17)
>       at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\markl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
>       at Liftoff. (C:\Users\markl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:192:16)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\markl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:17:3)

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have an old version of mean. The line that refers to has been commented out for a while and should probably be removed.

Now the gulpfile essentially redirects to the gulp directory, allowing the project to hold many separate gulp configurations.

https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/gulpfile.js

What version of MEAN are you using?